# Creating list of feature layers, running select by location, and returning results in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I want to perform Select by Location with a number of point layers and a corresponding number of polygon layers. For example, if I have a list of point layers (pt1, pt2, pt3) and a list of polygon layers (pg1, pg2, pg3), I want to know how many points in pt1 intersect pg1, and the same for pt2 and pg2, and pt3 and pg3. I eventually want to be able to turn this into a tool that can be used on various datasets.

I have been working on a Python script to accomplish this, and the first half works great, but the second half, not so much.

```
#Import arcpy and set working environments
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Z:\Scratch\ChristinaScratch\pythonpractice.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Create list of only point feature classes that are present within the 
workspace and convert to feature layers

pointFeatureClasses= arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Point", " ")
for fc in pointFeatureClasses:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc + "_pfl", "", "","")
    print fc
areaFeatureClasses= arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Polygon", " ")
for fc in areaFeatureClasses:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc + "_afl", "", "","")
    print fc


#for loop to iterate through each point and each area feature class in the 
list, select the points that intersect with the area feature class,
and return the number of records selected

pointFeatureLayers = arcpy.ListFiles("*_pfl.lyr")
areaFeatureLayers = arcpy.ListFiles("*_afl.lyr")

for fl in pointFeatureLayers:
    print fl
for fl in areaFeatureLayers:
    print fl

for point in pointFeatureLayers:
    for area in areaFeatureLayers:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("point","INTERSECT","area")
        result = str(arcpy.GetCount_management(point))
        count = int(result)
        print count
```

I am able to create the list of feature classes and convert them to feature layers without problem, but the rest of the script doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'm not thrown any errors, I'm just not getting anything. I just discovered that while the created feature layers are added to the map and are sourced back to my workspace gdb, when I look into my gdb through ArcCatalog they aren't actually there.

What is going wrong?

I'm fairly new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layers aren't being stored in the designated workspace. They aren't being stored in any workspace in fact, given the nature of layers. You're thinking of [Save To Layer File](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/save-to-layer-file.htm), which is different from [Make Feature Layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm). Since no layer file is being created `arcpy.ListFiles` is returning empty lists. Try this:

```
#create layers and add to lists
pointFeatureClasses= arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Point", " ")
pointFeatureLayers = []
for fc in pointFeatureClasses:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc + "_pfl", "", "","")
    print fc
    pointFeatureLayers += [fc + "_pfl"]

areaFeatureClasses= arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Polygon", " ")
areaFeatureLayers = []
for fc in areaFeatureClasses:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc + "_afl", "", "","")
    print fc
    areaFeatureLayers += [fc + "_afl"]

#sort lists so that point layers match polygon layers
sortedPntFL = sorted (pointFeatureLayers)
sortedPolyFL = sorted (areaFeatureLayers)

#enumerate point layer
for i, point in enumerate (sortedPntFL):
    #get corresponding area layer
    area = sortedPolyFL [i]
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(point, "INTERSECT", area)
    result = arcpy.GetCount_management(point).getOutput (0)
    count = int(result)
    print count
```